# Check Equality of two Named Matching groups using Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex, backreference

i have this regular expression:

```
<%(?<begintag>[^>]+)%>(?<inner>(.+?))<%/(?<endtag>[^%]+)%>
```

what i want to achive is, check for equality of **begintag** and **endtag** .
consider this input :

```
<%layout%>
    <%pagetitle="test">
        <%products%>
            <div class="product">
                <img src="<%product-smallimage%>" class="thumbnail" alt="<%product-title%>"/>
                <a class="buy-link" href="<%product-url%>"><%product-title%></a>
            </div>
        <%/products%>
```

is there any way to check this ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Warning - Regex is not a tool that can be used to correctly parse HTML. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/12971

Comment: i know. i don't want to parse html tags. i want to implement a template-based shop that can use different themes .

i should replace <%products%> inner htmls with appropriate information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Igor said, you can capture the the name of the opening tag, then use a backreference to match a closing tag with the same name.  There are a couple problems with his regex though; this one works:

```
(?s)<%(?<begintag>[^>]+)%>(.+?)<%/\k<begintag>%>
```

Here I've used a *named* backreference - `\k<begintag>` - instead of a numbered one - `\1`.  It's always a good idea to use named backreferences if you're using named groups, but in .NET it's essential.  In .NET, `\1` does *not* match the same thing as `(?<begintag>[^>]+)` just because it's the first group.

I also used Singleline mode - `(?s)` - to allow the dot in `(.+?)` to match linefeeds.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regex [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (`\1` below):

```
<%(?<begintag>[^>]+)%>(?<inner>(.+?))<%/\1%>
```

Comment: What precisely did not work? Have you escaped the backslash in a C# string?

Comment: i tried to test it in this [link](http://regexhero.net/tester) but it didn't work. i think Alan answered the reason.